# How to integration test a method which accepts SQL parameters ,on ABP framework which uses SQLite as in-memory DB?

Tags: sqlite, integration-testing, abp

I have the following base class method which accepts SQL parameters to run custom query.Using ABP testing framework which use SQLite as in-memory db, I am getting the below error while running the integration test.

```
 public int ExecuteNonQuery(string query, SqlParameter[] parameters, 
                             CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
```

> Message: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type >'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' to type >'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteParameter'.

The possible workaround is to use a localDB instead of SQLite. Is there any other solutions which could minimise the change in implementation here ?

Comment: Are you using EF Core?

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql:

> Entity Framework Core will parameterize SQL if you use format strings or string interpolation:
>
> ```cs
> // Format string
> var author = db.Authors.FromSql("SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {0}", id).FirstOrDefault();
>
> // String interpolation
> var author = db.Authors.FromSql($"SELECT * From Authors Where AuthorId = {id}").FirstOrDefault();
> ```
>
> > ❗ Entity Framework Core will only parameterize interpolated strings if they are supplied inline to the `FromSql` method call.